# Ubuntu 12.10 became Kubuntu 13.04

Tags: 12.10, 13.04

I upgraded Ubuntu 12.10 to Ubuntu 13.04 using the Update Manager. After upgrading I've just restarted and there's a splash sreen with Kubuntu Logo. I can't login to my Ubuntu account. I had installed KDE Desktop Manager but uninstalled it before upgrading.

Help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling lightdm:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove lightdm
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

Comment: I had installed Gnome 3 and GDM 3. Should I remove it too?

Comment: It will probably just ask you when you install which manager you prefer to use.

Comment: Ok I've reinstalled lightdm and then i have to reinstall AMD Drivers. Unity doesn't work just Gnome Classic. Why the GRUB entry is Kubuntu GNU/Linux? Do you know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue with the grub menu list, and here's how I fixed it.

The file `/etc/default/grub.d/50_kubuntu.cfg` passes on "Kubuntu" as the name of the distribution to `update-grub`. If you want to change it back to Ubuntu, the fix is as simple as:

```
sudo rm /etc/default/grub.d/50_kubuntu.cfg

sudo update-grub
```

If you want to change it to something else, just edit `/etc/default/grub` and change the `GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR` line to whatever you want. Example, change:

```
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
```

to:

```
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="My very own Ubuntu install"
```